remote: error: GH006: Protected branch update failed for refs/heads/development
I am using GitHub Actions to increment my angular project version as a last step in my workflow.
I configured the git user and git email before pushing (i.e, before running 'git push').
git config user.name "${{ secrets.GIT_USER }}"
git config user.email "${{ secrets.GIT_EMAIL }}"

I am getting below error
remote: error: GH006: Protected branch update failed for refs/heads/development.  
remote:
remote: - Changes must be made through a pull request.  
To https://github.com/my-repo-name.git
! \[remote rejected\] development -\> development (protected branch hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/my-repo-name.git'

I realised am not using any password or Git PAT for pushing so tried setting the git remote url as below
git remote set-url origin https://x-access-token:${{ secrets.GIT_TOKEN }}@github.com/thermofisher/de-instrument-storage-service.git

Additional context:

My repo is a private repo.

The branch ('development') I am trying to push has branch protection rule called Require a pull request before merging checked. Which I should not disable. And also the git user and email that I'm using have admin permission for the repository. So not sure why I am unable to push!


Is there any way, to be able to push changes via GitHub Actions to a protected branch as an admin?

try --force-with-lease

@jessehouwing, Tried git push --force-with-lease, didn't work getting the same error!

I think you need to bypass the user without having to meet pull request required protection rule --> you can refer this doc for more details -> https://github.blog/changelog/2021-11-19-allow-bypassing-required-pull-requests/

In that case the branch protection rule probably also prevents force pushes.

@DayanandaDR I tried bypass as well, thats when i realised if the git user is already an admin to the repo then no need to explicitly allow that user to bypass.

@jessehouwing yes protection rule might not allow force push as well.
Main thing i want to know is when running 'git push' how can i know if Gihub Actions recognises the git user (thereby recognise the user as repo admin) and allow for push.
Because in local via ssh or https i'm able to push... Github Actions is where i'm facing this issue.

It looks at the token used. It must be an authentication token for that user. It doesn't care about the commit username and email at all unless there is a metadata policy in place as well. The Actions token will always be recognized as GitHub Actions making the push, and you probably don't want to grant Github actions the permission to bypass policies, since that would allow it to bypass protections.

I had to pass the GIT Personal Access Token while cloning the repo..
- name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.GIT_TOKEN }}

From then on I am able to commit/push with the git user which has admin access to the repo and effectively able to bypass the "Require a pull request before merging" check.
I referred to the following:
https://www.paulmowat.co.uk/blog/resolve-github-action-gh006-protected-branch-update-failed
